# ShouldComponentUpdate is set to false child components do not update if props change

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle, react-lifecycle

My goal is to render a child component without re-rendering it's parent component.

So for example, App's state is passed as a prop straight to the Column component but Column is a child of Table and Table has `ShouldComponentUpdate` set to false (For example, table data didn't change..).

The problem.. if Apps state changes the Column component does not update.. unless `ShouldComponentUpdate` is set to `true` on the Table Component.. Is there anyway around this?

The documentation does say

> Returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering
>   when their state changes.

But doesnt mention if their props change..

For test purposes I've created a demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/k2072rkp7o

Preview of the code:

```
const Column = ({ isSelected, onClick, children }) => (
  <div 
    style={{
      backgroundColor: isSelected ? 'green' : 'red',
      padding: '10px',
    }}
    onClick={onClick}
  >

    Column: {children}

  </div>
);

const Row = ({children }) => (
  <div 
    style={{
      backgroundColor: 'teal',
      padding: '10px'
    }}
  >

    Row {children}

  </div>
)


class Table extends React.Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    // There will be logic here to compare table data to see if its changed..
    return false
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div 
        style={{
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        padding: '10px'
      }}>

      Table {this.props.children}

    </div>
    )
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isSelected: false
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Table>

        <Row>
          <Column
            isSelected={this.state.isSelected}
            onClick={() => this.setState({
              isSelected: !this.state.isSelected
            })}
          />
        </Row>

      </Table>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after more reading, it's not possible...  Which isn't good when you are playing with tables and want to apply a style to a cell component without causing a re-render of the whole table... Will have to look into alternatives...

Heres the component lifecycle for anyone who has same problem..

[image: React Component lifecycle]

Answer (score 1):

Consider a solution where you are setting a default state onload and updating state where there is interaction with your table appending an 'color-whateveryoulike' class to your columns. Props won't help you in this instance because we never want to update props, you're wanting to listen for state updates.

Answer (score 0):

U can use Table component to be PureComponent, and that PureComponent internaly checks for changes.

just change `class Table extends React.Component` to `class Table extends React.PureComponent` and then delete

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    // There will be logic here to compare table data to see if its changed..
    return false
  }
```

because, as i said, PureComponent does that internaly.
Read more at: [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)
But don't use it always, because it can have side efect to slow your app down if used to much for unnecessary things.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, `class Table extends React.PureComponent` is the same as `class Table extends React.Component` when `shouldComponentUpdate` is configured.  Anyhow, i've tried your solution and it still causes a re-render of Table.. Even though nothing has changed on Table, however, it's children did change.